# I want to change text strokes on hover ... how can i?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

In the initial state the fonts should be the same color, i.e black or other color, but when someone hovers on one `p` text the hover text should change its color and the rest of them change it into strokes while text-color is transparent and vice-versa,

When I hover out on the text it should go back to its normal color. I want to apply this in CMS content so it needs to take a dynamic values, if not dynamic but needed to at least change the colors and strokes.

```css
.style1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

.Ancestors {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #00f;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
}

.overAncestors {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="100" summary="">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="style1" valign="middle" onmouseover="this.className='overAncestors';" onmouseout="this.className='Ancestors';">vita</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="style1" valign="middle" onmouseover="this.className='overAncestors';" onmouseout="this.className='Ancestors';">mege</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="style1" valign="middle" onmouseover="this.className='overAncestors';" onmouseout="this.className='Ancestors';">Hita</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="style1" valign="middle" onmouseover="this.className='overAncestors';" onmouseout="this.className='Ancestors';">nitml</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="style1" valign="middle" onmouseover="this.className='overAncestors';" onmouseout="this.className='Ancestors';">rage</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that once the class `Ancestors` is added to the `<span>` tags, it is never removed again.

You can use jquery's `hover()` to adjust the `span` classes whenever there is a mouse over and mouse out event.

This is the idea of the algorithm:

```
$('.style1').hover(function(){

  //mouse over...
  //Add class 'overAncestor' in the span hovered
  //Add class 'Ancestor' in the other spans

}, function(){
    
  //mouse out...
  //Remove class 'Ancestor' and 'overAncestor' of all spans 

});
```

This is a snippet of the working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.style1').hover(function(){
    $('.style1').addClass('Ancestors');
    $(this).addClass('overAncestors').removeClass('Ancestors');
  }, function(){
    $('.style1').removeClass('Ancestors').removeClass('overAncestors');
  });
});
```

```css
.style1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

.Ancestors {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #00f;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
}

.overAncestors {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="100" summary="">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="style1" valign="middle">vita</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="style1" valign="middle">mege</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="style1" valign="middle">Hita</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="style1" valign="middle">nitml</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="style1" valign="middle">rage</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```